# Dynamically set params in snakemake

Tags: parameters, snakemake

I am trying to set up a snakemake pipeline which aligns reads again a reference genome.
The rule which indexes the genome has a parameter which needs the maxlength of the reads that will be mapped against the genome. Right now I have manually set this in the config.yaml file, but it would be great to set this depending on what input reads is given the pipeline. For instance by running a small awk snippet that finds the max length in all fastq files.

The pipeline can accept any given number of samples to map against the genome, but only the longest readlength in the sample should be used for building the index (which I'd rather just do the single time)

Is there some way to do this?

My current rule looks like this:

```py
rule index_reference_genome:
    """
    Index reference genome.
    """
    input: 
        ref_fasta=config['ref_fasta'],
        ref_gtf=config['ref_gtf']
    output: 
        directory("{outdir}/references/star")
    threads: 40
    params: 
        len=int(config['max_read_len'])-1,
        #star=config['star']
    log: "{outdir}/logs/star/index_reference_genome.log"
    benchmark: "{outdir}/benchmarks/star/index_reference_genome.log"
    conda: config['conda_env']
    shell: 
        """
        if [ ! -d {output} ] ; then mkdir {output}; fi;
        STAR \
            --runThreadN {threads} \
            --runMode genomeGenerate \
            --genomeDir {output} \
            --genomeFastaFiles {input.ref_fasta} \
            --sjdbGTFfile {input.ref_gtf} \
            --sjdbOverhang {params.len} &> {log}; #--outTmpDir {output}/STAR_tmp
        """
```

Comment: Why not calculate it as part of the shell command? Or you could use a python function doing that for you, as snakemake can take advantage of python.

Comment: Note that you can modify `config` as you wish using python code before declaring the rules. Assuming you have defined a function `determine_max_len`, this would be something like that: `config['max_len'] = determine_max_len(<insert args here>)`

Answer (score 0):

As @ManavalanGajapathy already adviced, you may do it in your shell script: it is complex enough already, so a small awk script could be added there.

Anyway, complex shell scripts are not so popular in Snakemake's `shell` section, so you still can calculate this length in the `params` section:

```py
    params: 
        len=lambda wildcards: getMaxReadLength(wildcards)
```

Now you need to implement this `getMaxReadLength` function that based on the values of the wildcards (if any) retrieves the max length of the reads:

```py
def getMaxReadLength(wildcards):
    return "".join(shell("Your AWK code here", iterable=True))
```

Comment: That looks like the way to go. I'll try this out, thank you.